# When calling function, it tells me the location of the object(list) rather the list itself?

Tags: python, function, oop, printing, return

```
class Knapsack:
  def __init__(self, capacity, objects):
    self.capacity = capacity
    self.objects = objects

  def newHillclimber(self):
    return lambda x: [randint(0,1) for x in range(1,11)]

k = Knapsack(20, 10)  
print(k.newHillclimber)
```

Why does it not print the list I return in newHillclimber? what does this mean :main.Knapsack object at 0x7f80407f8e10>>

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning a list in newHillclimber, you're returning a function that generates a list.  You also aren't calling the function in your outer code; you're just printing the function itself (which is a method on your Knapsack object).  If you want to return a list, remove the unnecessary `lambda` expression around the list comprehension.

```
from typing import List

class Knapsack:
  def __init__(self, capacity: int, objects: int):
    self.capacity = capacity
    self.objects = objects

  def newHillclimber(self) -> List[int]:
    return [randint(0,1) for x in range(1,11)]

k = Knapsack(20, 10)  
print(k.newHillclimber())
```